# How to correctly reference a html object in css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-transitions, create-react-app

A list with four items is displayed on my page. on hovering one of those, the background image is slightly moved. The tutorial i have now assigns the activeIndex (menu.dataset.activeIndex) of the div containing the four items an index number in a for each loop. now they are numbered 0-3 and i can console.log this.

each one is supposed to set the background to a specific position on hovering as following:

```
.menu[data-active-index="0"] > .menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -25%;
}
```

however, it does not happen. what is wrong with the reference or what is wrong elsewhere?

```
    import React from "react";

export default function App() {
    const menu = document.getElementById("menu");

    // this code makes it so the background pattern snaps back to its position after unhovering an list item
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item"))
        .forEach((item, index) => {
            item.onmouseover = () => {
                menu.dataset.activeIndex = index; // numerates elements top to bottom 0 to (length-1)
                console.log(menu) // <div id="menu" data-active-index="2"></div>
            }
        })

    return (
        <div className="menu">
            <div className="menu-items">
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
            </div>
                <div className="menu-background-pattern">
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

index.css:

```
.menu-background-pattern {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

  background-image: radial-gradient(
    rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 9%,
    transparent 9%
    );
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: 12vmin 12vmin;

    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;

    transition: opacity 800ms ease,
      background-size 800ms ease;
}
```

I pretty much just typed it down from the video, but maybe it is not working because it is a react application it is running inside. The transition of opacity and background-size is also working.

Comment: Your js references `menu.dataset.activeIndex`, while your css is targeting `.menu[data-active-index="0"]`; `activeIndex` is not the same as `active-index`. So either update your JS to `menu.dataset["active-index"]` or update your css to use `.menu[data-activeIndex="0"]`.

Comment: @mykaf   See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#javascript_access

Comment: hello, it produces an error when trying to assign menu.dataset["active-index"] as it is not a valid property name.

changing the CSS did not change the behavior of the background (none). 

also, by console logging the menu, i can see the reference is exactly referenced:
<div id="menu" data-active-index="3"></div>